# Laravel Mail function using IMAP instead of SMTP?

Tags: php, laravel, email, imap

I'm currently building an application and I have build a functionality to send mails in my Laravel application. However, the mails sent through this functionality use SMTP configuration as provided in the .env file.

Is it possible to use IMAP instead of SMTP, so the 'sent' mails will be shown in the sent folder of my webmail?

I took a look at the mail config, it looks like imap is not supported. Does anyone know how to do this? It would help a lot!

(`/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMAP is not a mail sending protocol (without rarely deployed extensions); if you could, it would _only_ appear in your Sent Folder, and not be sent.  You’ll either need to use a service that does this automatically (Gmail will put sent messages in the sent folder), or write a script on the server side to do this for you.